# How to do multiple of operations in Java Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, jersey

I am using `Java/REST/Jersey` webservice.

I have a users service,

```
..../rest/users/get/username
..../rest/users/get/all
```

...
I also want to do other things, like sports

```
.../rest/sports/get/sport
.../rest/sports/play..
```

I know I can map users to `rest1` servlet and sports to `rest2` servlet, in fact its what I have now. But, Is there a way to do both things (users and sports & ...) all in one servlet? I just don't like the fact that I will have `rest1,rest2,rest3,rest4`...

```
..../rest/users/get/username
..../rest/sports/play
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define service endpoints with patterns.

You should review your endpoints, 'cause `/rest/users/get/username` seems to make no sence for me. If you want to GET something, you will use the GET method. No need to have this in URL / Endpoint. Examples in code:

```java
@Path("/{parameter: rest1|rest2|rest.n}/users")
public class Users {

    // [rest1|rest2|...]/users/{userID}/username
    @GET
    @Path("/{userID}/username")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,...})
    public Response getUserUsername(@PathParam("userID") String userID) {
        // ... return username for specific user
    }

    // [rest1|rest2|...]/users/usernames
    @GET
    @Path("/usernames")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,...})
    public Response getUsernames() {
        // ... return all usernames
    }
```

If you really want to have it in a single resource class:

```
@Path("/{parameter: rest1|rest2|rest.n}")
public class Rest {

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,...})
    public Response getUsers() {
        // ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/sports")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,...})
    public Response getSports() {
        // ...
    }
```

... but pls don't do that ;)

Comment: But What you are showing looks vague, I want the API to do multiple things not just users, I want it to do ../users operations and I also want it to do  ../Searches operations and other stuff, I do like to have the name of what its trying to do. I think I found the answer of what I wanted, I can map all of them to one rest like ../rest/users , .../rest/sports, ...rest/searches ..

Comment: Jap, you can put everything into one /rest resource. But I recommend you to split it up into multiple resource classes.
Just build resource classes for each type of resource you want to have, class Users; class Sports; class Searches ... and define (f.e. @Path("/users")) so jersey can do the rest.